# Laravel Global scope for specific Routes and it's sub routes

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose there is a `Test` Model like this:

```
class Test extends Model
{
        public $primaryKey = 'test_id';
        public function questions ()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'question_test', 'test_id', 'question_id')->withPivot('weight');
        }
}
```

And a `Question` Model like this :

```
class Question extends Model
{
        public $primaryKey = 'question_id';
        public function tests ()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Test', 'question_test', 'question_id', 'test_id')->withPivot('weight');
        }
}
```

Question model fields are these:

```
question_id
text
correct
active  => can be true or false
created_at
updated_at
```

As you see there is a `ManyToMany` Relationship between these two models.

And I have two separate sections in my app, one for Admin users and other for public users.

Admin can perform any action on questions and tests. like add some question to tests , remove , edit and etc.

But in the other hand , public users can only tests and related question that are active(means their active fields are true).

Suppose some Admin routes are these:

```
http://myapp.dev/Admin/tests
http://myapp.dev/Admin/test/5/questions
http://myapp.dev/Admin/test/5/question/create
http://myapp.dev/Admin/test/5/remove
```

And some User routes are:

```
http://myapp.dev/Dashboard
http://myapp.dev/tests-list
http://myapp.dev/test/5/questions
```

For that , I know that I can use [query-scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes) like this in `Question` model :

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('active', 1);
}
```

And when I want to fetch only active questions must to do this:

```
$test->questions->active()->get();
```

But I have many action that perform on questions on the user Panels therefore that is hard and time consuming if want to use an `active()` method for select questions.

I can not use Global scopes because that Affects on all question queries that run in whole project.

Is there a way that can define global (or local ) scope for some specific routes and sub routes that public users can see those?

Or there are other ways to solve this problem?

**Update:**

In addition to those mentioned, Users can have some roles. For example an admin user can switch from admin panel to user panel. in this case I want to display only active question when he is on user panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping your routes in **middleware**. Create **HideInactiveQuestions.php** by running `php artisan make:middleware HideInactiveQuestions`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Question;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class HideInactiveQuestions
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        Question::addGlobalScope('active', function(Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('active', '=', 1);
        });

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Next, register your middleware in `Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ....
    'restrict.public' => \App\Http\Middleware\HideInactiveQuestions::class,
];
```

Now those routes which have been wrapped by this middleware (**restrict.public**) will be filtered by your scopes.